# Sum an array of numbers in Javascript using Recursion

Tags: javascript

Why isn't this working? I'm getting a stack too deep error:

```
var countRecursion = function(array) {
  var sum = 0
  var count = 0

  sum += array[count]
  count ++

  if (count < array.length) {
    countRecursion(array);
  } else {
    return sum
  }

}
```

Comment: Just an FYI: that's not exactly recursion, as you're not sending something as a parameter in your function and testing it to see if you've hit a base case. Something like that would be adding count as a parameter (initialized to array.length - 1), having array global, and returning array[count] + countRecursion(count-1), terminating when count is negative (returning 0).

What you have is closer to iteration, but in a function.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake and reset sum and counter inside the recursive block. I simply moved them outside.

```
var countRecursion = function(array) {

  sum += array[count]
  count ++

  if (count < array.length) {
    countRecursion(array);
  } else {
    return sum
  }

}

  var sum = 0
  var count = 0


countRecursion([1,2,3]);

alert(sum);
```

This code is not recursive but iterative. I am not 100% sure if that's what you really wanted. But since you mentioned it, some people down voted my answer since I only fixed your code, but didn't made it recursive I guess. For completeness, here is recursive version of your code:

```
var countRecursion = function(array, ind) {


  if (ind < array.length) {
    return array[ind] + countRecursion(array, ind + 1);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }

}

  var sum = 0
  var count = 0


sum = sum + countRecursion([1,2,3, 5, 6, 7], count);

alert(sum);
```

Comment: It happens. Glad to help =]

Answer (score 0):

For recursion: *pass* data up, *return* data down.

The original code has a *different* `count` variable, being a *local variable* defined in the function, that is initial set to 0. As such the base case is never reached and the function recurses until the exception is thrown.

In addition to using a variable from an outer scope (or another side-effect) this can also be addressed by by following the recommendation on how to handle recursion, eg.

```
var countRecursion = function(array, index) {
  index = index || 0; // Default to 0 when not specified

  if (index >= array.length) {
     // Base case
     return 0;
  }

  // Recurrence case - add the result to the sum of the current item.
  // The recursive function is supplied the next index so it will eventually terminate.
  return array[index] + countRecursion(array, index + 1);    
}
```

Comment: @torazaburo The array *is* passed *as is* the index. In a language with a functional-style list it would generally be accepted to pass the tail in the recursive call; but in JavaScript it would require an array slice.

Comment: @torazaburo It's 1) unnecessary and 2) changes the runtime complexity.

Comment: @torazaburo Using a slice for this particular task is "ugly". In JavaScript (as in, say C) - without a tail or iterator concept - this is a perfectly acceptable approach.

Comment: @torazaburo Absolutely not. Using slice or the equivalent in languages with a mutable array-list style implementation (since it *must make a new array and copy the data*) is **not the same tail** when used in this manner. It changes the complexity of the operation; if this were Scala, Haskell, or a LISP dialect - or with any data type that *supported* a tail - this answer would be different to reflect that. Slice *can* be used, yes. But *there is no benefit here, in JavaScript* except for personal opinion about "cumbersome" and "ugly".

Comment: @torazaburo And personal opinions about "cumbersome" and "ugly" are not warranting of down-votes. This answer explains the original problem and offers up a clean (yes, my opinion) solution that does not violate any functional concepts.

Answer (score -1):

I see what you're thinking.

The issue with your code is that everytime you call `countRecursion`, `count` goes back to 0 (since it's initialized to 0 within your function body). This is making `countRecursion` execute infinitely many times, as you're always coming back to `count = 0` and checking the first term. You can solve this by either:

1. Initializing `count` outside the function body, that way when you do `count++`, it increases and doesn't get reset to 0.
2. Passing `count` along with `array` as a parameter. That way, the first time you call the function, you say `countRecursion(array, 0)` to initialize `count` for you.

Note that you have to do the same for `sum`, else that will also revert to zero always.

Finally, (and this doesn't have to do with the stack error) you have to actually call `return countRecursion(array)` to actually move up the stack (at least that's how it is in C++ and what not - pretty sure it applies to javascript too though).

Answer (score -1):

Array sum using recursive method

```js
var countRecursion = function(arr, current_index) {
  
  if(arr.length === current_index) return 0;
  current_index = current_index || 0;
  return countRecursion(arr, current_index+1) + arr[current_index];
}

document.body.innerHTML = countRecursion([1,2,3,4,5, 6])
```